# NextJS: context is reset when routing when using Next-i18next

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context, next-i18next

I create a `Theme context` for my `nextjs` app.

This is `_app.tsx`:

```
function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <WrapLayout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
      </WrapLayout>
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

This is `WrapLayout.tsx`:

```
export const ThemeContext = createContext<ThemeData>({
  theme: GlobalTheme.LIGHT,
  setTheme: () => {
    //
  },
})

export const useThemeContext = () => useContext(ThemeContext)    

function WrapLayout({ children }: { children: ReactElement }) {
      const [theme, setTheme] = useState<GlobalTheme>(GlobalTheme.LIGHT)
    
      return (
        <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, setTheme }}>
          <div id="theme-layout" data-theme={theme} className="text-txt-primary">
            {children}
          </div>
        </ThemeContext.Provider>
      )
    }
```

The `theme` have 2 val: `light` and `dark`, `light` is **default**.

I have 2 `routers`: `/` and `/manager`

When I'm in `/manager` page, change theme to `dark`: `<div id="theme-layout" data-theme='dark' className="text-txt-primary">`.

Then rout to `/`, the context is reset: `<div id="theme-layout" data-theme='light' className="text-txt-primary">`

I have searched some information but not work.

How can I fix that?.

**Edit:**

The problem is Im using `next-18n`:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ locale }: { locale: string }) {
  try {
    return {
      props: {
        ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ['common'])),
      },
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      props: {
        ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, ['common'])),
      },
    }
  }
}
```

If I remove `i18n` everything work.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be ideal, but you can always store your theme in local storage, and each time, check if it is present, and if it is, use it.

Comment: Thank for ur ans. But I use `transition-duration: 300` to make the changes is softer. That mean each time `routing`, the `transition-duration` will be invoked, the page is from `light` to `dark` in 300ms, that is realy realy bad UX.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. :/